# How to build a menu with grid icons

Tags: android, menu, grid, icons

[image: how menu looks]

Hi people,

I want to build a menu with a grid of icons, is it possible?  How build like that image?

Comment: Use a `GridView`. Or a `LinearLayout`. Or a `ConstraintLayout`. Or, if there will be a lot of them, use a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` or `GridLayoutManager`.

Comment: Hi +CommonsWare, I like to build a menu layout, not a activity layout, it's a lot different

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what you mean by a "menu layout". Your screenshot does not resemble any sort of standard Android menu-like structure, such as an action bar or `Toolbar`. And, even with those, anything custom to this degree would use things like a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, meu layout is that resides on menu folder, look at Android Studio Project Structure, and this layout don't accept tags like LinearLayout, etc...  the image I post was for give an idea of I want to build  (sorry my poor english)

Comment: "meu layout is that resides on menu folder" -- that would be called a menu resource. There is nothing in Android that will take a menu resource and give you anything that resembles your screenshot. The closest thing is the [action bar](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) (sometimes called the app bar) or a `Toolbar`, and none of those look like your screenshot.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for your directions, I will look for something different for that